# Why chartjs is not drawing in interior of a div?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, canvas, chart.js

I have a problem with ChartJs, because I try to put in interior of a div with class="col-6", it's only working if that class="row" and don't understand why.

**pie-chart.components.ts:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.labels = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE"];
    this.chartInit();
  }

  chartInit() {
    let chartElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector("#myChart");
    chartElement.width = 750;
    chartElement.height = 750;
    this.pieChart = new Chart(chartElement, {
      type: "outlabeledPie",
      data: {
        labels: this.labels,
        datasets: [
          {
            backgroundColor: [
              "#FF3784",
              "#36A2EB",
              "#4BC0C0",
              "#F77825",
              "#9966FF",
              "#00A8C6",
              "#379F7A",
              "#CC2738",
              "#8B628A",
              "#8FBE00"
            ],
            data: [1, 2, 3]
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        plugins: {
          legend: false,
          outlabels: {
            text: "%l %p",
            color: "white",
            stretch: 20,
            font: {
              resizable: true,
              minSize: 12,
              maxSize: 25
            }
          }
        },
        responsive: true
      }
    });
  }
```

**pie-chart.components.html:**

```
<canvas id="myChart" height="750" width="750"></canvas>
```

**home.components.html:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 text-center">
        Available books
        <app-pie-chart></app-pie-chart>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 text-center">
        Lended books
        <app-pie-chart></app-pie-chart>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The code that is working** (but I don't want this version):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="row text-center">
        Available books
        <app-pie-chart></app-pie-chart>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-center">
        Lended books
        <app-pie-chart></app-pie-chart>
    </div>
</div>
```

So how can I display that two pie charts in interior of that two divs? And the second question is: why is only working in a div with class="row", and in a div without class or with other class it doesn't display anything?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a simple stackblitz? | maybe duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216621/how-to-fit-doughnut-chart-js-into-bootstrap-column

Comment: @JacopoSciampi thanks for the answer, but I don't think is duplicated. Here is the [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-1sj3p6).